# Multithread - function in another thread to be called several times

Tags: python, multithreading

Basic problem: I need to listen to a stream and at certain intervals (when a specific information is recievied from the stream) I want a separate function to be run but still continue to listen. I've understood that one way would be to use Threads where one thread listens and another performs the action. I have modified an online exampel to do it but it only calls the "act" function once, not everytime the event is set. Is there a way that the "act" function can be called based on events in the "stream" thread? (Note, there is no actual stream below, just a loop. Needed to simplify for this question. The event below is when j is equal to 3,6,9)

```
def act(e):
   logging.debug('Initiated - waiting...')
   event_is_set = e.wait()
   if event_is_set:
      logging.debug('Event is set, creates CS')
   e.clear()

def stream(e):
for j in range(10):
    logging.debug('j: {}'.format(j))
    if j in [3, 6, 9]:
        e.set()
    logging.debug('Event: {}'.format(e.isSet()))

e = threading.Event()

t1 = threading.Thread(name='block', target=act, args=(e,))
t1.start()

t2 = threading.Thread(name='non-block', target=stream, args=(e,))
t2.start()
```

Output:

```
(block) Initiated - waiting...
(non-block) j: 0
(non-block) Event: False
(non-block) j: 1
(non-block) Event: False
(non-block) j: 2
(non-block) Event: False
(non-block) j: 3
(non-block) Event: True
(block) Event is set, creates CS
(non-block) j: 4
(non-block) Event: False
(non-block) j: 5
(non-block) Event: False
(non-block) j: 6
(non-block) Event: True
(non-block) j: 7
(non-block) Event: True
(non-block) j: 8
(non-block) Event: True
(non-block) j: 9
(non-block) Event: True
```

The "act" function is called when j=3 but not for j=6 or j=9 even though event is true. I have obviously made an error but what would I need to do/change to get that functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `act` thread is finished.

If in your use case you are waiting for exactly three events, then you need a `loop` in your act function which will wait for the event thrice. If you want it listen for ever you need an infinite loop and a mechanism to kill the thread when you done with the stream thread.

```py
#if you are expecting exactly 3 events.
def act(e):
   for i in range(3):
       logging.debug(f'Initiated - waiting for event {i}')
       event_is_set = e.wait()
       if event_is_set:
          logging.debug('Event is set, creates CS')
       e.clear()
```